# Write files with strings in binary with python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary

I succesfully managed to convert integers to binary and write them in a binary file importing the struct module.

```
import struct

a = 1234

with open("data.txt", "wb") as f:
   f.write(struck.pack("i", a))
```

Now I would like to convert a string to binary so I can also write it in the binary file without converting the string to ASCII. What's the typecode to use for strings? Is there another way of writing a string in binary?

Comment: "Now I would like to convert a string to binary so I can also write it in the binary file without converting the string to ASCII" - what do you mean by "convert a string to binary"? What specific conversion do you have in mind? If you don't already know exactly what conversion you need, don't try to gloss over it. Getting this right, and *understanding* it, is important.

Comment: @usr2564301 I have to write a binary file. To do that, all the date needed for this file are integers except for one thing. I need to know store a string in that binary file so that the information is clear.

Comment: The binary-vs-ASCII difference is for integers only (well, and floats). Text can be written as-is into a binary file. Try it and then inspect the result with a file editor. There just is no 'other' form that a text string can be converted to.

Comment: Your ouput file name's extension is ".txt", but you are going to write binary data into. What is the real goal?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to write your utf-8 data to a file openend in a **binary-write** mode:

```
with open("file.txt","wb") as f:
    f.write(your_string.encode("utf-8"))
```

If you want to read utf-8 data from a file opened in a **binary-read** mode:

```
with open("file.txt","rb") as f:
    str_to_save_to = f.read().decode("utf-8")
```

The same can be done with("r" mode):

```
with open("file.txt","r") as f:
    str_to_save_to = f.read()
```

This is because when you write or read in the regular mode - python automatically converts the data for you from "str" to "bytes", and from "bytes" to "str". But these two things are actually the same thing with a different interface. When saved in memory these two types look the same(at least their essence).

Comment: This doesn't address the problem of storing a string in a binary data structure.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the typecode `'s'` to write a fixed-length binary string.  For example, `'10s'` specifies a byte string of length 10, as described [in the docs](http://You%20have%20to%20encode%20the%20string%20somehow.%20%20You%20can%20encode%20it%20with%20ASCII%20if%20you%20want,%20or%20UTF-8,%20but).

There are two important problems here:

1. The process of converting a string into a binary representation requires an **encoding**.  ASCII is one such encoding, and UTF-8 is another, more modern one.  You can encode a string like this in Python:

   ```
   'foo'.encode('utf-8')
   ```

   You can't just store a string in a binary stream without encoding it somehow.  How you do that is your decision to make.
2. A string is not usually a fixed-length data structure.  If you want to be able to read the string out of your data structure after writing it, you'll have to know how long it is. 
   Otherwise, how do you know how many bytes to read?  You can restrict yourself to storing strings with fixed-length binary representations (e.g., using `'10s'`), but this can cause problems with variable-width encodings like UTF-8 (where some characters are more than one byte).

   There are several different ways of encoding this information in a binary stream; for example [C-style strings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string) are terminated with a null byte (`b'\0'`), while it's more common to store the [length of the string first](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_(computer_science)#Length-prefixed) (as a prefix), and then write the bytes out.

String representation in binary is non-trivial, and you should think carefully about how you want to represent your data before proceeding.  See the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_(computer_science)#Representations) on strings for more detail.

---

**N.B.** If all you want to do is store a single string in a file, then this is done very easily using Shay's answer. In this case, the filesystem itself tells Python how long the file is (in bytes), and when to stop reading data.

This approach doesn't work when you're storing a data structure made up of lots of different pieces.